# Українська з півночі Молдови «...до ґіда...». Що може означати?

Tags: переклад, розмовна-українська, діалекти

Не могли б ви мені допомогти розшифрувати невеличкий текст? Це уривок зі сказаного старою бабусею з села з півночі Молдови. Вона розмовляє українською. Військовополонені під час Другої світової війни будували дорогу в Молдові, а вона з її матусею йшла пішки в матусине село. Шляхом до села вони перетинали цю дорогу. Я не вмію писати українською [початково це запитання було [записане російською](/revisions/5824/1) — прим. Sasha], тому записала сказане фонетично російською. Чи не знаете ви, що може означати «до ґіда»? Літеру «ґ» вона вимовляє як мʼяку російську «г<sup>ь</sup>». Це точно не назва села, оскільки назву села бабуся згадувала раніше й там нема навіть таких звуків.

> Они робили сошейку [дорогу — прим. Tanya M.]. А ми с мамой переходили до ґіда. Моя мама ведь из того села.

<sub>[Початково і в запитанні, і в фонетичному відтворенні було написано «гида», але, враховуючи пояснення, імовірно малося на увазі саме «ґ» й «і», тому я перетворив на «ґіда» — прим. Sasha.]</sub>

---

Could you please help me to figure out what "do gida" could mean? It's a fragment from an interview with an elderly woman from the Northern Moldova. She lives in a small village and speaks Ukrainian. During the WW2 she saw POWs building a road in Moldova. When she saw them, she and her mother were on their way to another village. They were walking by foot and had to cross the road to reach the village. She describes it this way:

> Oni robili sosheiku. A mi s mamoi perehodili do gida. Moya mama ved' is togo sela.

"Gid" is not the name of the village because she mentions the name earlier, and it does not contain any letters from the "gida". "G" sounds like "g" is the "gates", but with [Slavic partial softing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iotation#Sound_change).

Comment: Tanya M., I apologize if your question was too much edited. First of all, it was not in one of the languages allowed on this site; then it was edited to take subsequent clarifications from comments into account. Never-the-less, if you feel that something is expressed wrongly/imprecisely, you can change the text any time you wish. (P.S.: As for me, [the version of Paul Gor](/a/5829) about dialectical pronunciation shift from "до діда" to "до ґіда" now looks as the most plausible version.)

Comment: @Sasha Чому _гида → ґід_, але _із → из_?

Comment: @stegetsj, бо я подумав, що нема певності, що там самі «із» — каже ж дехто «инший», «иноді» тощо, можливо, у деякий регіонах й «из» кажуть, хтозна. А про «ґіда» зрозуміло з доповнень. Тож, наразі думаю: хай краще все, окрім ґіда, лишається з точністю до літери як в оригіналі.

Comment: Напевно сошейку = шоссе?

Answer (score 7):

Доєднаюсь и я до пошуків. 
Отож, [до ґіда].
Загалом, звук [ґ] не є характерним для української мови, проте може з’являтись діялектно в певних умовах замість инших звуків:

1. найчастіше — це спорадичне одзвінчення к → ґ (наприклад, кава → ґава — стало літературним). Тоді «до кіда». Але такого слова віднайти не вдалось.
2. крім того, в деяких діялектах вказаного регіону (додаю мапу з «Атласу української мови») відбувається своєрідне зміщення вимови м’яких дь, ть: дʲ → ґʲ, тʲ → кʲ (наприклад, дід → ґід, дівка → ґівка, тісто → кісто, тяжко → кєжко).
   Тож, можу припустити, що за такою вимовою тут заховано слово «до діда».
   [image: Мапа з «Атласу української мови»]

---

I'll join the investigation too.
So, [do gida].
In general, the [g] sound isn't typical for the Ukrainian language but may appear in dialectal speech under certain circumstances instead of other sounds:

1. most often — it's sporadic voicing [k] → [g] (for instance, *кава* → *ґава* — became standard). Then *до кіда*. But I can't find such work.
2. in addition, in some dialects of the specified region (see the map from the “Atlas of the Ukrainian language”), pronunciation of palatalized [dʲ], [tʲ] is shifted in an unusual way: [dʲ] → [gʲ], [tʲ] → [kʲ] (for instance, *дід* → *ґід*, *дівка* → *ґівка*, *тісто* → *кісто*, *тяжко* → *кєжко*).
   Therefore I can assume that here the words *до діда* are hidden under such pronunciation.
   [image: Map from the “Atlas of the Ukrainian language”]

Answer (score 1):

Я особисто не знаю, що це означає. Тим більше, що це може виявитися якесь місцеве слово. Якби Ви не зазначили, що це не назва села, то я б подумав саме про назву села.

З різних словників я бачу таке:

- *[Гід](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?wordid=18346&page=619)*, *ґід* —
  (1) професійний провідник для груп туристів, екскурсовод;
  (2) провідник (у широкому значенні); той, хто показує дорогу.
  Походить з французькою мови й у старійших словниках писалося як *ґід* (див. словники [Голоскевича](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D2%91%D1%96%D0%B4&dicts=11), [Кримського](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D2%91%D1%96%D0%B4&dicts=1&highlight=on); це загалом типово, коли запозичені слова спочатку вимовляються ближче до оригіналу, але з часом можуть втрачати первісне звучання). Припускаю, що раніше це слово частіше вживалося в широкому значенні, ніж зараз.
- *[Гід](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/9251-ghid.html#show_point)*, *[год](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/9661-ghod.html#show_point)* — застаріле для «рік».
- *[Гид](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?wordid=18266&page=619#lid_18266)*, *[гидь](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?wordid=18280&page=619#lid_18280)* (вимовляється через «и», а не через «і», і через «г», а не через «ґ», але хтозна, наскільки точно було передано, плюс можливі місцеві особивості вимови) —
  (1) щось гидке, неприємне; нечисть, бруд;
  (2) погана людина;
  (3) земноводна тварина або плазун.

Я особисто схиляюся до першої версії. Що бабуся підійшла до провідника або до головного. Але це може бути дуже помилкова версія.

Upd.: Зрештою, найімовірнішою мені все-таки здається [версія Paul Gor](/a/5829).

---

I personally doesn't know what that means. Especially that it could be some local word. If you haven't explicitly mentioned that it's not a village name, I would almost certainly think about a village name.

From various dictionaries, I see:

- *[Гід](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?wordid=18346&page=619)* —
  (1) professional guide for groups of tourists;
  (2) guide (in wide meaning); those, who shows way.
  It derives from French and was recorded as *ґід* in older dictionaries (see dictionaries of [Holoskevych](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D2%91%D1%96%D0%B4&dicts=11), [Krymskyi](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D2%91%D1%96%D0%B4&dicts=1&highlight=on); it often happens that loanwords at first are pronounced closer to original but then after some time lose the original pronunciation). I assume that earlier this word was used in the wide meaning more often than nowadays.
- *[Гід](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/9251-ghid.html#show_point)*, *[год](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/9661-ghod.html#show_point)* — obsolete for “year”.
- *[Гид](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?wordid=18266&page=619#lid_18266)*, *[гидь](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?wordid=18280&page=619#lid_18280)* (is pronounced with “и”, not “і”; and with “г”, not “ґ”; but I am not sure how precisely the word was transcribed, and also some local pronunciation peculiarities are possible) —
  (1) something disgusting, unpleasant; dirt, mud;
  (2) bad person;
  (3) amphibian or reptile.

I personally tend to the first version. That the elderly woman went to a guide or leader. But that could be a very wrong version.

Upd.: After all, I think that [the idea of Paul Gor](/a/5829) is the most likely.

Comment: Name of the village is the most logical answer. To confirm or disprove that version I checked several war-era maps of that area and did not find any village with similar name in that area. I also checked several dictionaries of Ukrainian and Moldovan/Romanian, but none of the words with similar spelling make sense. I guess it's a word from local dialect. Thank you!